# Top Padding On UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to add some padding to the top of my tab bar but I can't find a clear answer on how to do so. I'm coming from a SwiftUI background and still trying to get the hang of UIKit.

Below is my code and a screenshot of my current tab bar.

```
class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .secondaryLabel
        
        let home = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CoinListViewController())
        let nilView1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CoinListViewController())
        let nilView2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CoinListViewController())
        let nilView3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CoinListViewController())
        
        home.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")
        nilView1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        nilView2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "bitcoinsign.circle.fill")
        nilView3.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")
        
        home.title = "Home"
        nilView1.title = "Search"
        nilView2.title = "Coins"
        nilView3.title = "Account"
        
        tabBar.tintColor = .label
        
        setViewControllers([home, nilView1, nilView2, nilView3], animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does "add some padding" mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Push the icons down, farther away from the top of the tab bar @matt

Comment: You can't. The position of the tab bar items is not up to you. You could put a view above the tab bar item that looks like part of it, I suppose.

Comment: For that you need to do is create custom view that represent you tab bar and add that view as child of your MainTabBarViewController's view and hide system defined tab bar